# arise error Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I use tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

arise error Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I use tensorflow, my code is :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.utils import to_categorical

model = Sequential()
max_features = 100
model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=256))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print("model is ok ")
```

Comment: Did not happen to me, and code looks fine.  Perhaps it is related to the installation process.  Can you tell the versions of keras and tensorflow, which platform you are on, and how you installed the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`Segmentation fault` means that you tried to access memory that you do not have access. If you choose right combination of `Tensorflow`, `CUDA` and `cuDNN` will solve this issue. You can refer [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).

I was able to execute above code without any issues. Please refer the same as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM

model = Sequential()
max_features = 100
model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=256))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print("model is ok ")
```

Output:

```
2.5.0
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 256)         25600     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 128)               197120    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 222,849
Trainable params: 222,849
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
model is ok
```